# Does a workgroup assigned in a parallel for "grow" in the sections inside of it?

Tags: c, performance, openmp

i have a piece of code i want to run in multiple threads, but when i increase the number of threads to run, i don't get much speedup. After a point the more threads i have the worst it gets, to the point that is much worse than the sequencial run.

So i'm trying to get an idea of what may be the problem, and i was wondering if Open MP allows me to do what i want to do in the first place.

The code is basicly this.

```
int threads = omp_get_num_threads()/2;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1) num_threads(threads)
for(i =0; i<len; i++)
{
  #pragma omp sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
     do_stuf();
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
     do_stuf2();
    }
  }
}
```

Imagine i have 16 threads(on a 16 core machine). What i'm looking for is to make a workgroup of 8 cores working in the for loop, and when one of that threads need another one on the section inside the for loop(because there are two sections), i want them to use one of the threads that are basicly IDLE outside the workgroup i assigned.

Does OpenMP allow me to do what i want and i'm simply getting overhead on the managment of the threads? If so, when the "idle" thread it does the job, will it get separated from the workgroup assigned to the for or will it simply be idle again?

Or am i getting this all wrong and the sections aren't using the idle threads at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple solutions to tackle this problem, both using nested parallelism:

1. Pretty-much as you proposed, but simply adding a `parallel` to your `sections` directive, with a `num_threads(2)` (which would give `#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)`. This along with an initial `omp_set_nested(1)` enabling nested parallelism would just make what you wanted. However, that means that you will have to handle the initialisation / termination the nested thread pool every iteration of the enclosing loop. This may or may not add some overhead, depending on the quality of your OpenMP implementation...
2. To avoid the previous in-loop `parallel` directive, you can first create a team of 2 threads, both running the entire (nest-parallelized) `for` loop, and running only one of the `do_stuf()` functions depending on their id.

Here is what that would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void do_stuf1( int i, int tidl1 ) {
    printf( "1: idx %d tid level 1 %d, tid level 2 %d\n",
            i, tidl1, omp_get_thread_num() );
}

void do_stuf2(int i, int tidl1 ) {
    printf( "2: idx %d tid level 1 %d, tid level 2 %d\n",
            i, tidl1, omp_get_thread_num() );
}

int main() {
    int nbth = omp_get_max_threads() / 2;
    omp_set_nested( 1 );
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads( 2 )
    {
        int tidl1 = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads( nbth )
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            if ( tidl1 == 0 ) {
                do_stuf1( i, tidl1 );
            }
            else if ( tidl1 == 1 ){
                do_stuf2( i, tidl1 );
            }
            else {
                printf( "**** that's not good!\n ****");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, using 8 threads, this gives me this:

```
1: idx 6 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 2
1: idx 7 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 2
1: idx 8 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 3
1: idx 9 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 3
1: idx 0 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 0
1: idx 1 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 0
1: idx 2 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 0
1: idx 3 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 1
1: idx 4 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 1
1: idx 5 tid level 1 0, tid level 2 1
2: idx 0 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 0
2: idx 1 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 0
2: idx 2 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 0
2: idx 3 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 1
2: idx 4 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 1
2: idx 5 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 1
2: idx 6 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 2
2: idx 7 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 2
2: idx 8 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 3
2: idx 9 tid level 1 1, tid level 2 3
```